# How to send a sequence of AT commands to a serial port in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port, at-command

In Linux I need to send a sequence of AT commands to a serial port on e.g. `/dev/ttyS0`, which has to wait for an `OK` answer before the next command is sent. I could imagine doing something like

```
echo 'AT' > /dev/ttyS0
echo 'ATS0=0' > dev/ttyS0
...
```

but this does not evaluate the answer from the device on that port.

Is there a *very* simple way to **automate** this within a bash script, probably with the help of `socat` and/or `microcom` **but no tools which cannot found on the most simple linux system**.

Comment: How simple? Most Linux may have any number of tools installed very easily.

Comment: I really cannot tell for sure. Name me a tool and I can tell you if I am able to use that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you install the PPP package you can use the `chat` program that comes with it. Or you can use `kermit`. Or the `cu` program that comes with uucp.  But to do it with pure shell is trickier. You might be able to use the read and printf functions, with stdio redirected to the port.

some snippet:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 38400 raw
chat -f script.txt < /dev/ttyS0 > /dev/ttyS0
```

Should get you started.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But I tried to do `sudo bash -c "chat -v -f chat.txt < /dev/ttyS0 > /dev/ttyS0"` with the verbose action and the file consisting of `'' AT OK AT OK`, but got no output at all. Is it working or not? Did I oversee something?

Comment: You won't see anything normally, but it looks you you can use the `-sv` options to see it logged to stderr. The `-v` by itself logs to syslog. BTW, you could also use the `expect` tool.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing, but on android mobile. can this answer help me? if yes, what is ppp packet and who can I install it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a *very* simple way to **automate** this within a bash script:

```
$ (echo AT; echo ATS0=0) | atinout - /dev/ttyS0 -
AT
OK
ATS0=0
OK
$
```

by using the [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program which is written specifically with this functionality as its sole purpose. The output above is assuming `ATE1`; without echo the response from the modem will be `"\r\n\r\nOK\r\n\r\nOK\r\n"`.

In the example above, atinout will send the first command `AT` (properly terminating the command line with `\r`), wait until it receives a Final Result Code (e.g. `OK`) and first then continue processing the next command.

You can give input from a file by specifying that instead of the first `-`, and if you want to capture the output give a file name instead of the last `-`. You can use here doc instead of grouped echo commands if you like.

Answer (score 2):

To show the messages from:

```
echo -e "ATHO\r" > /dev/ttyACM0
```

or any other modem commands type `who` to find the terminal number then run:

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0 >& /dev/pts/8 &
```

Then the messages from the AT command will show on your terminal.

Comment: You can use `/dev/tty` for your current TTY and avoid the detour to check the correct one from `who`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error :

```
cat 'AT'
```

means *display AT file* wich not exists I guess.

Instead, try doing :

```
cat<<EOF>/dev/ttyS0
AT
ATS0=0

EOF
```

That uses [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) *here-doc*

Comment: ups, I meant echo of course. Also your answer does not answer my problem. How can I automate so all the commands are sent automatically.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to terminal
2. enter "sudo minicom -s"
3. go to "serial port setup" and set the serial port settings
4. enter "change with setting?"
5. enter "save setup as dfl". By dfl it means default
6. enter "exit"
7. Write any at command on the new open minicom terminal.