# Sending AT-Command to a serial port and getting the answer in android

Tags: android, linux, shell, su, ppp

I have 2 Question:

I want to send AT-Command to a serial port in android. so I did these steps:

1. rooted my mobile
2. install Terminal Emulator to insert unix command
3. insert:

   ```
   su
   ```

then:

```
    echo -e "AT" > /dev/smd0
    cat dev/smd0
```

or

```
     echo -e "AT" > /dev/ttyS0
     cat dev/ttyS0
```

both don't gave me the response.

I think there is no problem in echo command but how can I read the answer? (Q1)

in this link: [How to send a sequence of AT commands to a serial port in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878684/how-to-send-a-sequence-of-at-commands-to-a-serial-port-in-bash)

there is something close to my question but it seems that they insert the command on the computer not a phone. in both cases what is ppp packet and how can install it on my mobile
 and what dose it mean? (Q2)

Comment: Generally an actual serial port (assuming you have the right device at all) needs to be configured before you can use it.  `echo` may work for writing, but `cat` rarely works for reading from one.  I would suggest you compile and test some C code on a desktop linux, then once you have it correct port it to android either as a jni library (if app userid's have sufficient permission) or as an executable to use with your su hack.

Comment: but how can i do it on desktop?