# how to deal with the serial port in android mobile?

Tags: android, unix, serial-port, at-command

actually I know no thing about serial port. but I see an example of sending it an at-command:

```
echo -e "AT" > /dev/smd0
```

What is /dev/smd0 and why they sometimes replace it with /dev/ttyS0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending AT-Command to a serial port and getting the answer in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447365/sending-at-command-to-a-serial-port-and-getting-the-answer-in-android)  **Do not post a repeat of your own question**

Comment: Thank u for your notice. yes they are close because I'm working on a project and both of them are related to this project. But in this question I'm asking for information about the system of the mobile, where in the question of the link I'm asking for solution to a problem I have in my project. That's to be specific in the question. However you can feel the difference when you see the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/dev/smd0` and `/dev/ttyS0` are [device files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file). Such files are [virtual files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file) that provide a file I/O operation interface for working with some underlying thing like for instance hardware resources like serial ports, hard disks and memory, or with non-hardware resources like process information, random number input, terminal screen output, etc.

Device files comes in two flavours, character and block. Serial ports are character devices, you can verify with `c` being the first character in output from `ls -l`:

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 64 Apr  7 00:25 /dev/ttyS0
$
```

---

`/dev/ttyS0` is the device name used for serial ports on on linux desktop computers, corresponding to `COM1` in DOS/Windows (in the very, very early days of linux `/dev/cua` was used, you might occasionally encounter references to that). For virtual USB serial interfaces to mobile phones `/dev/ttyACM0` and `/dev/ttyACM1` are used. Some other devices use /dev/ttyUSB0. For Android there are a few different device file names in use where `/dev/smd0` is one of them. Your phone might use another one, so you have to check what you should use specifically for your phone.

---

The command `echo -e "AT" > /dev/smd0` does not make sense. The `-e` option enables interpretation of backslash-escaped characters, but since the following string contains no such characters it is equivalent to just `echo "AT" > /dev/smd0`.

However, when sending AT commands to a modem, the command line should be terminated with only `\r` and nothing else. This is mandated by [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en).

So the proper command to send the command "AT" to the modem should be

```
echo -n -e "AT\r" > /dev/smd0
```

---

But even when getting as far as sending the AT command correctly to the modem, you must read back the responses from the modem. Closing and (re-)opening the device file several times while doing this (which you will do by running a sequence of shell commands) is not a good way to go about, so I would recommend that you use my program [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) which is specifically written to be used for command line AT command communication:

```
$ echo AT | atinout - /dev/smd0 -
AT
OK
$
```

or

```
$ echo AT > input.txt
$ atinout input.txt /dev/smd0 output.txt
$ cat output.txt
AT
OK
$
```

This way you will get all modem communication performed correctly.

Comment: How can I implement your c code on android. Is porting C code by JNI is useful way?

Answer (score 0):

1. Using c4droid
2. Open .c file
3. Modify line 173 to printf("atinout version ...\n"); ... is version number
4. Now compile your code in c4droid
5. retrieve file from c4droid directory cp data/data/com.n0n3m4.droidc/files/temp /sdcard